# idk FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: html

I don't know why I am getting this kind of error
Where should I fix this error and will it run fine?

```
               from urllib.request import urlopen
            from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
            from urllib.parse import quote_plus

            baseUrl = 'https://search.naver.com/search.naver?                    where=image&sm=tab_jum&query='
            plusUrl = input('검색어를 입력하세요 : ')
            # 한글 검색 자동 변환
            url = baseUrl + quote_plus(plusUrl)
            html = urlopen(url)
            soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
            img = soup.find_all(class_='_img', limit=2)

            n = 1
            for i in img:
                imgUrl = i['data-source']
                with urlopen(imgUrl) as f:
                    with open('./img/' + plusUrl +         str(n)+'.jpg','wb') as h: # w - write b - binary
                        img = f.read()
                        h.write(img)
                n += 1
            print('다운로드 완료')
```

under the code is error

```
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "index.py", line 17, in <module>
                with open('./img/' + plusUrl + str(n)+'.jpg','wb') as h: # w - write b - b
            inary
            FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './img/현빈1.jpg'
```

idk

Comment: Post the actual code, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `./img` directory exists. The `'wb'` option will only create the file itself but not the directory.

In general, for this error, I would say check to make sure the path that you are trying to write to exists.

Answer (score 0):

considering `./img` is in the same directory level as of parent folder of your code and you are using linux based system.

so you need to use `../` to traverse back to the previous directory. so your code should be `with open("../img/", <other data>)` then `open("./img/",<other data>)`